# C++ / DLNA: Generate DLNA.ORG_FLAGS

Tags: c++, dlna

I try to develop some kind of DLNA Media Server in C++ running on Linux. Currently, i struggle at generating the needed DLNA.ORG_FLAGS value. I found the following help on the internet:

```
/* DLNA.ORG_FLAGS, padded with 24 trailing 0s
 *     80000000  31  senderPaced
 *     40000000  30  lsopTimeBasedSeekSupported
 *     20000000  29  lsopByteBasedSeekSupported
 *     10000000  28  playcontainerSupported
 *      8000000  27  s0IncreasingSupported
 *      4000000  26  sNIncreasingSupported
 *      2000000  25  rtspPauseSupported
 *      1000000  24  streamingTransferModeSupported
 *       800000  23  interactiveTransferModeSupported
 *       400000  22  backgroundTransferModeSupported
 *       200000  21  connectionStallingSupported
 *       100000  20  dlnaVersion15Supported
 *
 *     Example: (1 << 24) | (1 << 22) | (1 << 21) | (1 << 20)
 *       DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000[000000000000000000000000] // [] show padding
 */
typedef enum {
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_SENDER_PACED               = (1 << 31),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_TIME_BASED_SEEK            = (1 << 30),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_BYTE_BASED_SEEK            = (1 << 29),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_PLAY_CONTAINER             = (1 << 28),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_S0_INCREASE                = (1 << 27),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_SN_INCREASE                = (1 << 26),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_RTSP_PAUSE                 = (1 << 25),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_STREAMING_TRANSFER_MODE    = (1 << 24),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_INTERACTIVE_TRANSFERT_MODE = (1 << 23),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_BACKGROUND_TRANSFERT_MODE  = (1 << 22),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_CONNECTION_STALL           = (1 << 21),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_DLNA_V15                   = (1 << 20),
} dlna_org_flags_t;
```

But now i can't figure out how to get a String containing the needed "DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=xxxx". So my question is how can i get the needed string out of this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same trouble with this. Here is the solution i came up with:

```
typedef enum 
{
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_SENDER_PACED               = (1 << 31),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_TIME_BASED_SEEK            = (1 << 30),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_BYTE_BASED_SEEK            = (1 << 29),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_PLAY_CONTAINER             = (1 << 28),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_S0_INCREASE                = (1 << 27),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_SN_INCREASE                = (1 << 26),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_RTSP_PAUSE                 = (1 << 25),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_STREAMING_TRANSFER_MODE    = (1 << 24),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_INTERACTIVE_TRANSFERT_MODE = (1 << 23),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_BACKGROUND_TRANSFERT_MODE  = (1 << 22),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_CONNECTION_STALL           = (1 << 21),
  DLNA_ORG_FLAG_DLNA_V15                   = (1 << 20)
} dlna_org_flags;

std::string dlnaFlags = "";
char dlna_info[448];

sprintf(dlna_info, "%s=%.8x%.24x", "DLNA.ORG_FLAGS", DLNA_ORG_FLAG_TIME_BASED_SEEK | DLNA_ORG_FLAG_BYTE_BASED_SEEK | DLNA_ORG_FLAG_STREAMING_TRANSFER_MODE), 0);
dlnaFlags = std::string(dlna_info);
```

Now as this example shows, this code makes the string "dlnaFlags" contain the needed String "DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=xxxx". With time based seek, byte based seek and streaming transfer mode as an example.

Answer (score 1):

No need to invent wheel. If you have no problem with licensing you can check gupnp.
About DLNA flags, they have it like this:
http://sourcecodebrowser.com/gupnp-av/0.6.0/gupnp-dlna_8h.html#a1c454f2ab71f6a5f53ba955850917370